# Add Background Fetch to iOS7 app to grab web data via AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am writing an iOS 7 app that loads 600 employee records into a SQLite DB using AFNetworking and a REST web service. When the app first loads I check to see if the db exits, if it doesn't I copy over the blank employee.db and then call the web service and populate the db. This works well so far.

Now I need to add a background fetch service so I can periodically update the data. Somewhat at a loss as to how to do so. I understand that I need to add that capability to the target, which I have done. Need to write the App Delegate method setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval.

Then I can write the

performFetchWithCompletionHandler

method in the app delegate

It would be pretty simple to call my method that clears the db and recalls the web service. And I think it will get done in 30 seconds.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there some way to easily see if the data has changed? I suppose I could just write a tmp db and then compare the SQL dbs, but will that take too much time? Maybe jt doesn't matter, if I only check 4 times a day say as the data will almost probably change and only a bit.
2. I am worried about my method ending before I am done. Don't want to kill the current db if my temp one isn't finished. Maybe I should do the temp one and only if I have enough time left, like > 1 second, then delete current db and rename temp one to current name.
3. Is there a way I can prevent the possible problem that the user might be accessing some data when I am deleting the old db and renaming old to new? I need to suspend the ui or something like that, but don't know how.

Am looking for any direction or help here, and it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this I'd have the server send a timestamp for the data which you would send back so that the server would only need to send you data that had changed since the timestamp. This would solve your 1st question about how to know if there were any changes.

I'd then parse the (presumably) XML from your server and update the DB, but make the very last step be the one that saves the timestamp.

If iOS terminates your app before it writes the timestamp then the worst case is that next time it syncs it will re-request the data and attempt to re-apply it.

i.e. don't delete the old db and replace it with a new one... do it incrementally.